Is there a way to lock the tokens on for solana 2022 program?
Trying to vest tokens create with Solana Program 2022
tried using https://github.com/Bonfida/token-vesting/tree/master/cli but it calls the wrong program ID , any solutions ?
here is the error i get :
thread 'main' panicked at src\main.rs:108:14:
called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: incorrect program id for instruction", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(1, IncorrectProgramId)), logs: Some(["Program CChTq6PthWU82YZkbveA3WDf7s97BWhBK4Vx9bmsT743 invoke [1]", "Program log: Entrypoint", "Program log: Beginning processing", "Program log: Instruction unpacked", "Program log: Instruction: Init", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program CChTq6PthWU82YZkbveA3WDf7s97BWhBK4Vx9bmsT743 consumed 9773 of 600000 compute units", "Program CChTq6PthWU82YZkbveA3WDf7s97BWhBK4Vx9bmsT743 success", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]", "Program log: Create", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]", "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize", "Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 884 of 584634 compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 6477 of 590227 compute units", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: incorrect program id for instruction"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(9773), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }) }
Thank you
